# Search if a term already exists in an older research

Tags: data, terminology, library, digital-libraries

My research led me to introduce a term that describes a certain group of web applications.

In order to ensure that the term does not already exist, I searched on IEEE, ACM and Elsevier libraries, using keywords, but I feel this search is incomplete.

What is the most efficient way to search for a term by name (search for the word "MyTerm" in all the archives)
and search a term by context (search for a derm that defines specific characteristics of a group of applications, in all the archives).

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just Google?

Comment: @jakebeal Google is way too general, I want to target academic and research archives, as many of them as possible

Comment: Google Scholar then?

Comment: Use Google scholar with double quotes e.g. "terminology".

Comment: I second google scholar, also try https://www.google.com/?q=terminology+site:edu which restricts your search to US universities.

Comment: Possibly also try [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can understand what you are looking for, it seems that Google Scholar is likely to provide what you need.  As with most search engines, you can request literal terms and can constrain your search in various ways. Moreover, Google Scholar has fairly comprehensive reach across scientific documents (including much ["grey literature"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_literature)), while still being restricted to the scientific and technical realms.